# How do I get the 'find' command to skip over the files in the .git/ directory?

Tags: unix, find, grep

How can I get the Unix `find` command to omit the files in the .git/ directory? I've been using

```
find . | grep -v .git
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `prune`option:

```
find . -type d -name .git -prune -o -print
```

Or better yet, use [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/) to do grep like searches.